# Quelle est la meilleure construction: elle doit être au mieux de sa forme depuis « son opération », « qu’elle a été opérée », « après qu’elle a … »?

Tags: sens, formulation, reformulation

J’imagine qu’elle est au mieux de sa forme

…depuis son opération/le début de sa convalescence.

…depuis qu’elle a été opérée/ qu’elle a commencé sa convalescence.

…après qu’elle a été opérée/ après qu’elle a commencé sa convalescence.

Pour dire que là, actuellement, elle n’a jamais été aussi en forme après son opération; elle ne l’a pas été sur toute la durée, depuis l’opération jusqu’à aujourd’hui, elle est en super forme aujourd’hui, ce qui n’était pas le cas les journées précédentes en remontant jusqu’à l’opération.

Je cherche donc des tournures qui ne prêtent pas à des interprétations multiples (dans l’éventualité où je ne me fais pas des idées) ou qui rendent l’idée que je cherche à exprimer. Il est question d’un évènement ponctuel.

Contexte:

> Dans une vidéo que mon père a envoyée récemment, on voyait ma mère prendre un gin tonique au restaurant *Normandin*! J’en déduis qu’elle doit être au mieux de sa forme depuis son opération!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Les deux premières phrases signifient que la très bonne forme dure depuis le début de la convalescence, ce qui ne respecte pas le contexte. La troisième ne convient pas au contexte parce que c'est une hypothèse concernant le moment auquel le meilleur de la forme est constaté ; le locuteur suppose que ce moment se trouve après la convalescence.

- J’imagine que depuis qu'elle est en convalescence il n'y a pas eu un jour où elle se sera trouvé en aussi grande forme.
- J’imagine que depuis son opération c'est son premier jour de grande forme.
- J’imagine qu'elle est en grande forme, comme jamais auparavant depuis son opération.